# How can I create a (C) function to read data from a file into a linked-list using 'read'?

Tags: c, io, linked-list

I am trying to create a function that reads all characters in a given file into a linked-list, returning a pointer to the list. I cannot use fopen, fread, or fclose. I have confirmed that this is working code if operating on a string:

*Note that ft_lstnew creates a link with the content as the first peram, returning a pointer to that link.*

```
head = ft_lstnew(&str[i++], 1);
curr = head;
while(str[i])
{
    curr->next = ft_lstnew(&str[i++], 1);
    curr = curr->next;
}
curr->next = ft_lstnew(&str[i], 1);
```

How can I alter this code to operate on character in a file instead of in a string using the read function?

### My Attempt

```
t_list *ft_lstnew(void const *content, size_t content_size);

t_list *read_tetriminos(char *file)
{
    int fd;
    char c;
    t_list *curr;
    t_list *head;

    fd = open(file, O_RDONLY, 0);
    read(fd, &c, 1);
    head = ft_lstnew(&c, 1);
    curr = head;
    while(curr->content != EOF)
    {
        read(fd, &c, 1);
        curr->next = ft_lstnew(&c, 1);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    close(fd);
    return(head);
}
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Can I edit this post and have it be re-opened if it meets this criteria?

Comment: but certainly !

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre makes some good points, however because this question is more of a request of how to _refactor_ a function to a different _specific purpose_ (which is different from _improving a working function_ ) I feel it is reasonable to  vote for reopen.

Comment: the length of the question has been reduced a lot. Reopening sounds good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. The only thing that you are doing wrong is assuming that `read` will write `EOF` inside the provided buffer when reaching the end of the file. `EOF` is just a special value used by higher level functions provided by `stdio.h` to signal the end of a `FILE` object has been reached. Furthermore, `EOF` is not a `char`, but a `int`. Here you're using raw syscalls such as `open` and `read` to accomplish your task, and `EOF` has nothing to do with those.

You can take a look at the [manual page for `read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) to see what happens when the end of the file is reached:

> `ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);`
>
> `read()` attempts to read up to `count` bytes from file descriptor `fd`
>   into the buffer starting at `buf`.
>
> On files that support seeking, the read operation commences at the
>   file offset, and the file offset is incremented by the number of
>   bytes read.  **If the file offset is at or past the end of file, no
>   bytes are read, and `read()` returns zero.**

Therefore, your program can be re-written like this (I also added some error checking):

```
t_list *read_tetriminos(char *file)
{
    int fd;
    ssize_t nread;
    char c;
    t_list *curr;
    t_list *head;

    fd = open(file, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        // Open failed.
        return NULL;
    }

    nread = read(fd, &c, 1);
    if (nread == -1) {
        // Read error.
        return NULL;
    } else if (nread == 0) {
        // File is empty.
        return NULL;
    }

    head = ft_lstnew(&c, 1);
    curr = head;

    while (read(fd, &c, 1) == 1) // You can check for errors here too, this is just simplified.
    {
        curr->next = ft_lstnew(&c, 1);
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    close(fd);
    return head;
}
```